# How to render text in TextView which has URL apparence

Tags: android

Can you please if how can I render text `TextView` with URL like appearance (blue text with an underline)? And it can mixed with regular text (display as plain text)? And when I click on it, it will launch `WebView` loading that URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [autoLink](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setAutoLinkMask%28int%29) parameter of TextView.

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a button, image button, etc. and run a method kinda like this on press:

```
private void openLink(){

Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
supportIntent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.example.tld/"));    
this.startActivity(i);  }
```

But Karan's solutions is probably more straight forward for your purpose.

Cheers
Johe